# Read single parquet file in parallel in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

We work with Spark 1.6 (and also Spark 2.1) and operate on Hive-table which are saved as parquet files. In certain cases we have only few files (some 10 MBytes in size).

For example having two parquet files, reading those tables using `sqlContext.table(tableName).rdd.count` creates a sparkjob with only 2 tasks which take quite some time (~12 s).[image: Screenshot from SparkUI]

My question is : Is it possible to read `N` files with more parallelism than only `N`? Is there a way to speed up this spark job without changing the number of files on the filesystem? As HDFS is a distributed filesystem (and files are replicated), I can imagine that more than 1 machine can read (a part) of a file simultaneously.

Comment: Did u ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

up
Using several executors and/or several threads (with spark.task.cpus>1)